# Git pretty format short format date doesn't work

Tags: git, git-log

I have an alias for listing commits in customized pretty format, that contains the author date in short format, i.e. **YYYY-MM-DD**, for which I use the `%as` placeholder. It used to work fine until a couple of days.

Long story short, `git log --pretty=format:%as` should print the author date in short format, but it only prints `%as` for each commit line.

I tried other date format like
`git log --pretty=format:%aD` and `git log --pretty=format:%ad`, and they seem to work fine.

I am experiencing this in Git Bash on Windows 10, having git version 2.24.1.windows.2

As a reference, I have used [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) for the pretty format.

Anybody knows what could be the issue, or is there any workaround?

Comment: Which version of Git do you have? `%as` seems to have been added sometime around v2.25.

Comment: @Biffen you are right, but I had it working for a couple of months. I'll try updating the git version.

Comment: A small clarification: [`%as`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emasem) prints the _author date_ in short format, while [`%cs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emcsem) prints the _commit date_.

Comment: That's right @EnricoCampidoglio, I corrected the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, thanks to the insightful comment from @Biffen. Apparently, the `%as` placeholder was not available in the version I was using [2.24.1](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats/2.24.0). Updating to [2.29.2](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats/2.28.0) fixed the thing.

The only logical explanation would be that I had the aliases transferred from another laptop, and probably the 'new' laptop had already installed older git version.

Thanks @Biffen.

Answer (score 0):

To have the comment of @Biffen rounded up in an answer. This feature has been added in version 2.25.0 as the git documentations shows [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats/2.25.0#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-as).